# Where can I set last login time when using ASP.NET and Owin?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

I have implemented authentication using ASP.NET identity. The login is actually performed in this method of the OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider:

```
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "El nombre de usuario o la contraseña no son correctos.");
            return;
        }

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
           OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
    }
```

At that point, I don't have access to the User table where a field called "lastLoginAt" exists. I need to update that field to the date and time when the user logged in.

I have also a custom user store which has a method defined this way:

```
public Task UpdateAsync(T user)
```

but that method will be called if the User entity has to be updated.

Where do you suggest to add the code to update the last login date and time?

Answer (score 0):

As for me I used it this way.

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ExtractorDbContext());
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
        var user = await manager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user != null)
        {
            string roleName = manager.GetRoles(user.Id).FirstOrDefault();

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("UserId", user.Id));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Username", user.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Email", user.Email));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("FirstName", user.FirstName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("LastName", user.LastName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("LoggedOn", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Role", roleName));
            context.Validated(identity);
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

You can modify your  `ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity` same way of my `ClaimsIdentity`.

Comment: Thanks... I have done it, but I need to know the other part now. Where does the actual user saving occur? i am using a custom user store. I have placed a breakpoint at UpdateAsync method of the user store that receives the IdentityUser as parameter. My custom IdentityUser contains the LastLoggedOn property but i could not find where i need to implement the actual record persistance to database.

Comment: Have you tried to use that function the same line with your ClaimsIdentity?